# Symfony 2: how to make firstname and lastname in one column in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

now we have firstname and lastname fields, how to make firstname and lastname in one column in Symfony2?

for example:

```
label = fullname
input box = firstname input box + lastname input box
error message =  fullname error message, this is based on firstname and lastname
```

LIKE datatime.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on form theming:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: while it is the answer to the question (at least, as far as I understand the question), we prefer to quote the relevant information for the link into the answer, instead of link only answers

Comment: Bad questions get bad answers.

Comment: Can you give me a sample? Very Thanks!